# Pass arg to execl after strtok

Tags: c, shell, command, exec, strtok

I have to pass this series of command to a process, `strtok` them and execute with `exec`.

The commands are:

```
mkdir prova
rm prova/test
touch prova/test
ls
cp prova/test prova/test2
```

What I did till now is:

```
    char *token, *cmd, *params, path[30] = "/bin/";

    token = strtok(m_cmd.cmd, " ");

    cmd = token;

    while(token != NULL){
        //printf("[server] Token: %s ", token);
        params = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "");
    }
    /* other code */
    execl(path, cmd, params, (char*)(0));
```

My problems are two:

1) When I got `ls` how can I execute `execl` without params?

2) When I try to execute `cp prova/test prova/test2` it take `prova/test prova/test2` as one parameter and not two.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First of all you need to figure out a way of keeping track of the arguments ("params" as you call them), and if there are none you should not pass any to the [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) function. Secondly, take a look at that second `strtok` call, is that really the separator you wanted? Thirdly, I think that `execv` would be a better candidate if you have an unknown number of arguments.

Comment: Yes noticed that later. I fixed with a " " separator and used an array of pointers for params instead of a pointer. It seems to work

Answer (score 0):

1) According to the man page `exec(3)` the first parameter shall be the name of the command anyway (argv[0]), and not the first argument (argv[1]).

2) Yes, obviously. Within your `while()` loop you overwrite `token` and `params`, thus, token will become the 1st param and params the 2nd.